# Why is the std::accumulate function showing the wrong sum of a vector<double>?

Tags: c++, vector, accumulate

Consider the following code for adding all the elements of a `vector`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<numeric>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{

   std::vector<double> V;
   V.push_back(1.2);
   V.push_back(3.6);
   V.push_back(5.6);
   double sum = accumulate(V.begin(),V.end(),0);

   cout << "The sum of the elements of the vector V is " << sum << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

When I compile this on Cygwin on Windows and run it, I get the output at the terminal as

> The sum of the elements of the vector V is 9

The `accumulate` function seems to be rounding down all the numbers and adding them up, which would explain the answer.

Is this something wrong with the Cygwin g++ compiler, or my misinterpretation of the `accumulate` function for adding up a `vector` of `double`s?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`std::accumulate` is declared as such:

```
template <typename InputIt, typename T>
T accumulate(InputIt first, InputIt last, T init);
```

The second template argument to `std::accumulate` is deduced as `int` because `0` is of type `int`. Pass a double instead, like `0.0`.

Comment: Oh dear! This seems like a misfeature to me. Is it not more logical to deduce type from looking at the nature of the elements of the vector? Is there any use to this way of defining accumulate?

Comment: @smilingbuddha It is possible to write a wrapper that chooses the type of `init` using `typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type` instead of a template parameter. I believe that this isn’t done because it would be less flexible, though I’m not sure.

Comment: @rightfold Why not just convert the value by the container's `value_type`?

Comment: @remyabel `std::accumulate` works with iterators, not containers.

Comment: @smilingbuddha See my answer. I posted an example.

Comment: @rightfold: With current C++, that could be dealt with via `std::iterator_traits`, but `std::accumulate` predates that.

Comment: @JerryCoffin see my first comment. Good point about the chronology, though.

Comment: This is exactly why I've started a `"numeric2.h"` header in my project. There really should be a 2-argument overload using `std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type()` as initial value. If the type is "numerical enough", `value_type` will be a sensible zero value.

Comment: After banging my head against this problem for a while I found your answer. Thanks. Strange that even with specifying `std::plus<float>()` it still takes the template from the init value.

Answer (score 6):

Change `0` to `0.0`. It then gets `10.4` for me. While the container is double, the type deduction is `int` because of the initial argument passed to `std::accumulate`. Therefore, the container is assigned `int` values.

Comment: You may use `decltype(*first)` for `vt`.

Comment: Note that with your `accumulate`, you may have opposite problem : `accumulate<uint8_t*, int>` where result stands in `int` but not in `uint8_t`. And using `accumulate` to offset an pointer is no more possible (`accumulate<size_t*, T*>`) with your version (or any other usage where `T` and `decltype(*first)` are unrelated).

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes--probably want to do something like `decltype(std::declval(vt) + std::declval(T))` to get the result as whatever type the addition would/will give. This will let the user force promotion to a wider type, but not (probably accidentally) truncate to a narrower type.

Answer (score 6):

The value being returned from the std::accumulate function is an integer, not a double because of this:

```
double sum = accumulate(V.begin(), V.end(), 0);
//                                          ^-- Integer!
```

The template parameter inference done by the C++ compiler makes the return type of the `accumulate` function the same as the `init` parameter, which in your case is an integer. Therefore the return value is being rounded to the nearest whole number. The return value is then being implicitly cast back into a double when it's assigned into `sum`.

To fix this, you can simply pass the zero as a double (i.e. `0.0`) instead.

Answer (score 3):

The last argument of the [**`std::accumulate`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) call determines the type of the internal sum as well as the return type. Since `0` is an `int` everything gets rounded down during addition, and the result is an integer as well.